По какой формуле рассчитать вероятность выигрыша в лотерее при заданном количестве билетов
Лотерея типа 5 из 36, а точнее k из n.
Количество исходов определяется по формуле Си=n!/(n-k)!/k!
А по какой формуле посчитать вероятность выигрыша при "неслучайном" заполнении m билетов?
Т.е. если я заполню все варианты лотереи, не повторяясь , т.е. m=C, вероятность 100 %
Правильная ли такая формула вероятности Св=1-(Cи-m)/Cи ?

Определите -  что означает "неслучайном" заполнении? Если это неповторяющиеся сочетания, то формула верна.

Вас интересует выигрыш именно всех 5? Ведь 4 тоже выигрыш, но поменьше, нет? :)

Действительно, а как посчитать вероятность выигрыша при k-1 и k-2?
